# Database connection through aws secret manger

Tags: amazon-web-services, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, secret-key, aws-secrets-manager

i have secret key for db connection on AWS secret manager. I am retrieving through this code https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/php/example_code/secretsmanager/GetSecretValue.php

Now how i connect with DB using this credential from AWS secret manager.

I am using yii2
Thanks

Comment: The yii framework has a `yii\db\Connection` class that allows you to supply credentials. Retrieve the credentials from Secrets Manager and supply them to the Connection constructor.

Comment: Will you help me how to that @jarmod

Comment: Have you used `yii` previously? If not, I'd recommend searching for tutorials. Using the AWS PHP SDK is also well documented.